# Need to precisely set Highcharts axis min/max after chart creation

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Most of the time, our app wants to let Highcharts decide the y axis tick positions for a chart. But the user can select a "Customize Range" command and specify custom min and max for the y axis after the chart has been created and shown. Purpose: user may want to export charts that line up with other charts they've made. I have tried a number of things including the following code, but Highcharts continues to follow its own preferences for the min, max and tickInterval (e.g. it does not respect {5,25} or {-5,35}. And my custom tickPositioner callback is not being called.

```
okClicked() {  
    this.axis1.startOnTick = false;
    this.axis1.endOnTick = false;   
    this.axis1.alignTicks = false;
    this.axis1.tickPositioner = this.getCustomTicks.bind(this, this.axis1, this.yMin1, this.yMax1);
    this.axis1.setExtremes(this.yMin1, this.yMax1);
    this.axis1.chart.redraw();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vrwxunqa/
If yes, let me know so I create a full answer and describe it more precisely.

Comment: @raf18seb : putting {5,25} in your fiddle demonstrates my problem. thx

Comment: Just use "tickInterval: 5" or calculate any other value.

Comment: @raf18seb try tickInterval=5, min= -5, max=35 in fiddle. Same issue.

Comment: Everything looks fine in jsFiddle in my answer. If you're still using link from my comment, increase height of the chart in HTML.

Comment: It appears that several answers were correct, that I need to call update() on the axis (passing in min, max, and tickInterval in an options object). It seems I won't need to use a custom tick proc for my situation.

Comment: Using update() is the best approach, it gives us a lot of flexibility. If you have any other specific question, I will be happy to help you, just specify your question precisely. If you've got your answer already, please mark it as accepted. Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fire chart.update function after the button is clicked, and set axes options to whatever you want them to be:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function(chart, i) {
        chart.yAxis[0].update({
            max: 25,
            min: 5,
            startOnTick: false,
            tickInterval: 5
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/obfudy23/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve this issue by adding a simple input field to your html like this:

```
Min: <input id="min"> <br>
Max: <input id="max">
<button id="update">Update y-axis </button>
```

Then we need a function which activates on click of the button. Inside this function we will update the Highcharts chart.

```
$('#update').click(function () {
    chart.update({
       yAxis: {
           min: document.getElementById("min").value,
           max: document.getElementById("max").value,
           tickInterval: 5 //do calculations here to get needed tickInterval
       }
    })
});
```

As shown in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yszcfLdx/22/), it alters the y-axis. You can extend the update function however you like, just override the previous settings like happened in the code shown above.

On a sidenote: It has to be noted that in the fiddle the y-axis can be off at times, depending on the inserted values. The tickInterval should be dynamically calculated for this to work.

Comment: If you plug in {-5, 25} in the fiddle, you'll see my issue. I need to override Highcharts' smart tick generation.

Comment: @JoeNolan See my updated answer: you can just override tickInterval within this update as well to solve the problem. I set it on 5 for the demo purpose.